# How can you drop a unique, multi-column index in PSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, psql

I have added the following index to one of my tables:

```
add_index :referral_codes, [:campaign, :subscriber], unique: true
```

I then wanted to test the speed gains by adding it, but I am unable to drop the index from my psql database. According to the docs it isn't possible, but they offer no explanation as far as I can tell:

[DROP INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-dropindex.html)

...There are several caveats to be aware of when using this option. Only one index name can be specified, and the CASCADE option is not supported. (Thus, an index that supports a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint cannot be dropped this way.)...

I ended up rolling back my migration to check, but there must be a native psql way, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop any PG index with the SQL:

```
DROP INDEX <INDEX NAME>
```

rails generates index names automatically for you. You can see the list of defined indexes if you connect to your database using `psql` and type: `\di`. This will output a list of indexes currently defined for your database. Simply copy the name over to the `DROP INDEX` command and you should be good to go.